# retreiving ArrayList as a session attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, session-variables

Suppose I got class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class UrlEntry implements Serializable
{
    private String shortUrl;
    private String longUrl;
    private long clicks;


    public UrlEntry(String shortUrl, String longUrl, long clicks)
    {
        this.shortUrl = shortUrl;
        this.longUrl = longUrl;
        this.clicks = clicks;
    }


    public String getShortUrl()
    {
        return shortUrl;
    }
    public void setShortUrl(String shortUrl)
    {
        this.shortUrl = shortUrl;
    }
    public String getLongUrl()
    {
        return longUrl;
    }
    public void setLongUrl(String longUrl)
    {
        this.longUrl = longUrl;
    }
    public long getClicks()
    {
        return clicks;
    }
    public void setClicks(long clicks)
    {
        this.clicks = clicks;
    }

    public UrlEntry(){}


}
```

This is code from controller servlet

```
HttpSession session =  request.getSession(true);
ArrayList<UrlEntry> list = new ArrayList<UrlEntry>();
list.add(new UrlEntry("abc","site1.com",1));
list.add(new UrlEntry("def","site2.com",2));
list.add(new UrlEntry("ghi","site3.com",3));
session.setAttribute("urls", list);                     
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

This is part of code from index.jsp 
this works well

```
<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("urls")%>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
<%=(ArrayList<UrlEntry>)request.getSession().getAttribute("urls")%>
```

with error

```
UrlEntry cannot be resolved to a type
<%=(ArrayList<UrlEntry>)request.getSession().getAttribute("urls")%>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Should I declare UrlEntry as serializable?
Maybe some problems with the constructor?

Comment: did you import UrlEntry in your jsp?

Comment: yes. I did. I got problem when casting to arraylist<UrlEntry>

Comment: but without casting all works fine.No error

Comment: you have this in your jsp? <%@page import="packageName.UrlEntry"%>

Comment: Yes that was the issuue. The problem fixed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to first import the UrlEntry class in the jsp page.

```
<%@page import="packageName.UrlEntry"%>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is raised by the JSP compiler. It tells you that you need to add an import  directive for `UrlEntry` to the JSP page.